# Open.json file from API

Tags: json, api, python-requests

could anyone provide the code to open the content of this file?

url = 'https://datos.madrid.es/egob/catalogo/202625-0-aparcamientos-publicos.json'

I have tried **requests.get(url).json()** and I just keep getting the following error no mather what I do:

**JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is expecting a User-Agent header. Try:

```
import requests

url = 'https://datos.madrid.es/egob/catalogo/202625-0-aparcamientos-publicos.json'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.json())
```

Outputs:

```
{'@context': {'c': 'http://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal#', 'dcterms': 'http://purl.org/dc/terms/', 'geo': 'http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#', 'loc': 'http://purl.org/ctic/infraestructuras/localizacion#', 'org': 'http://purl.org/ctic/infraestructuras/organizacion#', 'vcard': 'http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#', 'schema': 'https://schema.org/', 'title': 'vcard:fn', 'id': 'dcterms:identifier', 'relation': 'dcterms:relation', 'references': 'dcterms:references', 'address': 'vcard:adr', 'area': 'loc:barrio', 'district': 'loc :distrito', ...
```

To get the @graph object just use normal JSON parsing:

```
print(response.json()['@graph'])
```

Or if you want it as a string:

```
import json
...
print(json.dumps(response.json()['@graph']))
```

Or iterate over the graphs objects:

```
for graph in response.json()['@graph']:
    print(json.dumps(graph))
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. Two questions: 1) What does the content of 'headers' mean? 2) Why does it just open a part of the json? I want to open what is inside '@graph'...

Comment: The headers content tells the server what browser or spider made the request, the server can then decide what to send back and in what format see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent It shows all of the JSON it was just too big for me to post in SO. If you want just the @graph element use see my updated answer.